# iOS UIImageView animationImages not updated after superview being added-to-subview

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have a small problem about the animationImage UIImageView.
I begin with creating an UIImageView with animationImages and add it as subview of another view, named baseView:

```
UIImageView* imageToday = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(YOUR_FRAME)] autorelease];
[baseView addSubview:imageToday];
imageToday.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PNGIMAGE_1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"PNGIMAGE_2"], nil];
imageToday.animationDuration = 2.0f;
imageToday.animationRepeatCount = 0xFFFF;
[imageToday startAnimating];
```

For some reason, the superview, baseView, will be re-added-to-subview to its superview.
Then when I try to update the animationImages of imageToday and restart the animation, the animation-images are not changed.

```
imageToday.animationImage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PNGIMAGE_3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"PNGIMAGE_4"], nil];
[imageToday startAnimating];
```

The simple hierarchy of the views:

```
- UIViewController
    - baseView
        - imageToday
```

If the base view-controller is shifted out (present/push) and back (dismiss/pop) by the navigation-controller, or if I press device HOME button and come back to my application, the animationImages in the above code section is changed correctly and shown on UI.

Any suggestions or solutions will be much appreciated! Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I didn't use removeFromSuperview on baseView while re-adding it to the parent view-controller's view, but just add again and let UIKit to manage the view hierarchy for me as the code below shows

```
[self.view addSubview:self.baseView];
```

Comment: I think you need to explain the sequence of events that cause this problem more clearly, and give more detail. Why for instance, would basView be removed from the controller, and then re-added?

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, thanks for replying and sorry for not clarifying my problem more specifically. The baseView is not removed, but just added to its superview's subviews. I let UIKit to manage the hierarchy of baseView and the parent view-controller.

Comment: Then I don't understand this: "the superview, baseView, will be re-added-to-subview to its superview" baseView can't be re-added if it isn't removed. Is baseView the view controller's self.view, or is it added to that?

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, all I did to self.baseView is add it again to self.view's subview (like the codes I updated at the bottom of the post). I believe that UIKit will remove the formerly added self.baseView and add it again to the very front of the view-controller's (self.view) hierarchy, am I right?

Comment: Hi @rdelmar, our app passed the Apple Store audition and now available on the store. We found that the distribution version didn't suffer from this issue.